# regex for simple math equation

Tags: java, regex

I want to recognize integers or decimals and the four simple operations, broken into tokens
I can't get the decimal to work, can you please help?

My reg is

```
expression = "2.7 + 3 * (1 + 2)";
String expRegString = "\\d+(\\.\\d+)*|[\\(\\)\\+\\-\\*\\/]";
Pattern expPattern = Pattern.compile(expRegString);
Matcher expMatcher = expPattern.matcher(expression);

while (expMatcher.find()){
    System.out.println(expMatcher.group());
}
```

gives me `"+", "3", "(" , "1", "+" , "2",")"`

Edit: the correct result would be `"2.7","+", "3", "(" , "1", "+" , "2",")"`

Comment: What should be correct result? Would it be `2.7` `+` `3` `*` `(` `1` `+` `2` `)`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to specify

Comment: Is it just for this particular equation, or do you need it to match different equations also?

Comment: For the beginning of your regex (the 2.7 part), I think you want `?` rather than `*`. That means `\\d+(\\.\\d+)?`

Comment: Java has a tokenizer library class called StreamTokenizer that should work for your case out of the box...

Comment: Yea match different equations, but only  integers or decimals and the four simple operations and oh the parentheses

Comment: @user16547 It also doesnt work

Comment: @waterling Why are you using a regular expression for this? You should simply code a simple lexer/tokenizer. Regular expressions aren't the right tool for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @plalx There's actually other things I have to recognize, like units of the values (cm, mm etc)

Comment: @waterling That's an even better reason not to rely on regular expressions only. It's not smart enough, especially if you want to report syntax errors or invalid expressions such as unbalanced parenthesis.

Comment: @waterling If you have another requirements like units then why you didn't mentioned them in your question. This way you are just wasting your and others time. I agree with Plax that regex is not best tool for this kind of task.

Comment: Because I want to solve it on my own. Anyway, thanks, guys, for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try removing all spaces and then split your data on every place that is before or after characters `-` `+` `*` `/` `(` `)`.

This should do the trick

```
String expression = "2.7 + 3 * (1 + 2)";
String[] tokens = expression.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("(?<=[-+*/()])|(?=[-+*/()])");

for (String token : tokens)
    System.out.println(token);
```

Output

```
2.7
+
3
*
(
1
+
2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may works for you:

```
expression = "2.7 + 3 * (1 + 2)";
String expRegString = "\\d+(\\.\\d+)*|\\(\\d+(\\.\\d+)*[\\+\\-\\*\\/]\\d+(\\.\\d+)*\\)";
```